# API fetching in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native, api, android-emulator, localhost

my name is Leo, I'm a newbie in Reactnative
I'm trying to make a login to my app and i met a problem with fetch API.
i recieved [TypeError: Network request failed]. I run on device API 30
here is my code:

```
const loginHadle = async(email, password)=>{
        await fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"email": email, "password":password})
        }).then(response=>{
            if(response.status==200)
            {
                response.json().then(data=>{
                    signIn(data.email, data.tokens);
                })
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log("reponse :", res); 
           }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return { name: "network error", description: "" };
          });

    }
```

and I've already add this line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

here is what i receive on postman
[image: postman result]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

On Android 9 because of the "http" and issue resolved by just adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> . . . </application>
```